# ASP.NET MVC Identity with Unity updated to v5 error with DBContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I got the following exception:

> Member 'IsLoaded' cannot be called for property 'Claims' because the entity of type 'ApplicationUser' does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet<ApplicationUser>.

Here's a message of that same exception:

[image: Hi]

I've updated my ASP.NET MVC application from Unity v2 to Unity v5 and I'm now getting the above error in my ApplicationUser class when trying to sign in.

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(
        this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);           

    return userIdentity;
}
```

Any ideas what might be the cause?

Stack trace:

```
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalNavigationEntry.ValidateNotDetached(String method) +178
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalNavigationEntry.get_IsLoaded() +19
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.AreClaimsLoaded(TUser user) +300
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<EnsureClaimsLoaded>d__63.MoveNext() +66
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetClaimsAsync>d__21.MoveNext() +204
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<GetClaimsAsync>d__103.MoveNext() +464
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__19.MoveNext() +1459
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
Data.Identity.<GenerateUserIdentityAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\Git\OPOC-Master\Data\Identity\ApplicationUser.cs:51
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<SignInAsync>d__16.MoveNext() +211
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<SignInOrTwoFactor>d__23.MoveNext() +814
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +38
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__24.MoveNext() +1389
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
Services.Web.Identity.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in D:\Git\OPOC-Master\Services.Web\Identity\ApplicationSignInManager.cs:33
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +175
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManagerExtensions.PasswordSignIn(SignInManager`2 manager, String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean shouldLockout) +127
Services.Web.UserService.PasswordSignIn(String email, String password, Boolean rememberMe) in D:\Git\OPOC-Master\Services.Web\UserService.cs:190
Web.Controllers.<Login>d__3.MoveNext() in D:\Git\OPOC-Master\Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:45
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +35
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9873049
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

And the following is the DI registration

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();    
container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();    
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, OPOCDbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());    
container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));    
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(OPOCDbContext)));
```

And the ConfigureAuth in Startup as follows:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<OPOCDbContext>());
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>());
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationSignInManager>());
```

UserService.PasswordSignIn:

```
public SignInStatus PasswordSignIn(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
    var result = _signInManager.PasswordSignIn(email, password, rememberMe, shouldLockout: true);

    return result;
}
```

ApplicationSignInManager (_signInManager):

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {

    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var userManager = (ApplicationUserManager)UserManager;

        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager);
    }

    public override async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

        if (user == null || !user.IsEnabled)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(SignInStatus.Failure);
        }

        return await base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, rememberMe, shouldLockout);
    }
}
```

ApplicationUserManager:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserDto> _userRepository;

    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IUserRepository<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserDto> userRepository) : base(store)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;

        #region User Config

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        this.PasswordValidator = Shared.Identity.PasswordPolicy.PasswordValidator();

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        this.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        this.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        this.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        this.EmailService = new EmailService();
        this.SmsService = new SmsService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = Startup.DataProtectionProvider;

        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            this.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public override async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, object>>[] includeExpressions =
        {
            c => c.Claims,
            c => c.CompanyUsers.Select(d => d.Company.CompanyModules)
        };

        var user = await _userRepository.SelectByIDAsync(includeExpressions, 
            c => c.Id == userId);

        if (user == null) return null;

        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace?

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks for your interest. Have added stack trace.

Comment: The StackTrace shows an error in the AccountController when it calls `UserService.PasswordSignIn` but the only code you've provided is for the method `GenerateUserIdentityAsync()` which doesn't use UserService.PasswordSignIn.  Please provide all relevant code (whatever method is on line 45, what `userservice` is etc).

Comment: Hi Erik, I've edited the question to provide the relevant info. Does the above help or is there more needed? Many thanks for taking an interest!

Comment: Hi Mate are you getting error on this line.   return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager);

Comment: Hi Max...yes that's right. And on this line in that method: var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);. I've given up and reverted to the old version of Unity